# Calling a javascript function while passing PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying use a javascript function while passing php variables in it. For example:

```
onclick="alert(<?echo $row['username']?>)";
```

Now this does not work, instead gives an error-`ReferenceError: Can't find variable:right_username`(here the right_username is the answer i expect in the alert).

However if instead of `username` i use `EmpID`:

```
onclick="alert(<?echo $row['EmpID']?>)";
```

EmpID being an int in the database works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$row['username']` is a string, you need quote it, or the javascript will think it as a variable.
`$row['EmpID']` is a number, so it shows.

```
onclick="alert('<?echo $row['username']?>')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your quotes:

```
onclick="alert('<?echo $row['username']?>')"
```